# Add a static value to each row in a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge, prepend

I have a 2d array as illustrated below:

```
[
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
]
```

I'm trying to prepend a column to it as illustrated below:

```
[
    ['X', 1, 2, 3],
    ['X', 4, 5, 6],
]
```

Using `array_unshift()` will cause the elements to become shuffled and I need their order to be retained. I also tried `array_merge()` as well as "adding" the new column with the existing array.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: sorry but i tried `array_unshift` and it wasn't shuffled.  canyou show how you used `array_unshift `?

Comment: Could you post it as answer so I can accept it? Thanks! By the way, if I may ask another thing. What's the best way to sort by index for the columns? I did a ksort($array) but it only sorted the rows by index.

Comment: adnswer posted. i quite dont understand. you want to sort the keys?

Comment: Yes. Because when the array was created, the elements were inserted not in order because it is based on a coordinate system. Now, in order to make sure that they're not messed up during unshift, I need to first sort the keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = array(
    array(1,2,3),
    array(4,5,6)
);

foreach($arr as $k => $v){
    array_unshift($arr[$k],"X");
}
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_map` and `array_push` like as

```
$arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]];
$result = array_map(function($v, $a) {
    $v = array_merge([$a],$v);
    return $v;
}, $arr, ['X', 'X']);

print_r($result);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/471822)

Comment: Isn't that doing the exact opposite? appending instead of prepending?!

Answer (score 0):

For a modern, functional-style snippet, make iterated calls of `array_merge()` upon a dynamically generated array of arrays containing your new value and your original array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3GLFv))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        'array_merge',
        array_fill(0, count($array), ['X']),
        $array
    )
);
```

Or: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/O3lsX))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($row) => array_merge(['X'], $row),
        $array
    )
);
```

---

For a concise, classic loop, modify the original elements/rows by reference as you iterate. Again, this approach modifies the original array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Ioa48))

```
foreach ($array as &$row) {
    array_unshift($row, 'X');
}
var_export($array);
```

---

If you want to append data to the end of each row, then reverse the order of row and static data in the `array_merge()` call: `array_map(fn($row) => array_merge($row, ['X']))`.

When merging data with non-numeric keys, you may be able to use the union operator (`+`) to merge instead of `array_merge()` or `array_replace()`.  If using the union operator, be careful that shared keys do not impede the desired values from being used in the result.